# What was the first written Russian-language story featuring travel to another inhabited celestial body?

Tags: aliens, space-exploration

What was the first written Russian-language story, whether a novel, play or poem, that featured travel to another inhabited celestial body, such as a planet, satellite or comet?

Comment: Not sure about priority, but [Red_Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_(novel)) is probably one of the earliest relevant books.

Comment: Sidenote: _inhabited comet_ sounds very strange.

Comment: I'm not nominating this, but *The Land of Crimson Clouds* is definitely a great space-travel-to-inhabited-planet story.

Comment: @Hindmost - Thanks for this, but Russian space-travel fiction long predates Alexander Bogdanov's _Red Star_ (1908). Pyotr Mashkov's _Correspondence of a Moonman with an Earthman_ was published in 1842; Vasily Lyovshin's _The Newest Voyage_, which features a trip to the Moon, in 1784. But I don't know whether Mashkov describes travel from Earth to Moon or whether Lyovshin describes the Moon as inhabited. There may have been earlier works. I was hoping someone here might know.

Comment: @Gallifreian Sure that's a great story, but it doesn't feature _aliens_.

Comment: @hindmost, it features *lifeforms*.